# Which technology should I use to develop a high performance web application

Tags: c#, java, python

I have couple of ideas in my brain which I would like to bring out before it's too late. Basically I want to develop a web application which I could sell it to clients. So which technology shall I use to accomplish this? I have been a C and C++ software developer but it's been a very long time since I have developed one. So the things I would like to know is:

1. Scalability and Performance?
2. Easy way to develop web application in a faster manner?
3. Any Framework?
4. Application server?
5. and which programming language?

Comment: Whatever technology you choose, this resource is a must read; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site

Comment: This issue, generically speaking, is not about a particular technology, but rather how you use it. There are some frameworks targeted at building fast and scalable web applications, however, even with those, is your use of them that will determine how well does the application ultimately perform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I would suggest using C++ with [CPPCMS](http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/wikipp/en/page/main)** as it's becoming stable and **is precisely targeted at high performance web applications**.

See if [the rationale](http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/wikipp/en/page/rationale) match your goals.

Answer (score 6):

Usually the programming language doesn't really matter. All have their own strengths and weaknesses. All come up with their own best-practices and frameworks.

It's really up to you what's your preference. If you  are coming from Microsoft C/C++ I'd use .NET, if you are from Linux world I'd use Java.

Back in the 90s Java was well known as a slow framework, however there was much of myth and the framework architecture is dramatically changed since that. Today, there is no generally *slow* or *fast* framework.

You can find thousands of sites in the web that tell you that the one or the other is faster. However, at the end of the day it depends on how you implemented your solution and how you utilized the best features of the framework.

Greets
Flo

Answer (score 3):

Build with:

1. C#, you'll love it (I'm also an old C++ developer)
2. [ASP.Net MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) ([Validation](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx), [caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385986/caching-in-asp-net-mvc), [Spark view engine](http://sparkviewengine.com/))
3. Any ORM having a [cache](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/24/nhibernate-2nd-level-cache.aspx) layer (I prefer [nhibernate](https://web.archive.org/web/20090831053827/http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/04/01/your-first-nhibernate-based-application.aspx))
4. Database with lots of allocated memory

Answer (score 1):

I kinda think this is almost more like a religious problem, than a real technical issue. For almost every programming language you can find a big website that's using it.
.NET -> Microsoft
Ruby -> Twitter (yes, they have a few issues, but still)
PHP -> Facebook
Java -> Lots of finance companies

Don't know about Phyton, but I'm sure there is.

More important is a good scalable architecture. That is where Twitter kinda screwed it up it seems.

Personally I use ASP.NET. Works fine, is somewhat easy and has a nice IDE. And the market is not so fragmented. Before I used Java with Websphere. Was running on a Sergenti Sun Box, so could definitely handle a lot.

I would more see into what you can get yourself into the quickest. If you know C++ C# or Java are easy to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163854.aspx).

Using ASP.NET has got a lot of advantages, and it is very performant. Here you've got a short list of some advantages:

> 1. ASP.NET drastically reduces the amount of code required to build large applications.
> 2. With built-in Windows authentication and per-application
>      configuration, your applications are
>      safe and secured.
> 3. It provides better performance by taking advantage of early binding,
>      just-in-time compilation, native
>      optimization, and caching services
>      right out of the box.
> 4. The ASP.NET framework is complemented by a rich toolbox and
>      designer in the Visual Studio
>      integrated development environment.
>      WYSIWYG editing, drag-and-drop server
>      controls, and automatic deployment are
>      just a few of the features this
>      powerful tool provides.
> 5. Provides simplicity as ASP.NET makes it easy to perform common tasks,
>      from simple form submission and client
>      authentication to deployment and site
>      configuration.
> 6. The source code and HTML are together therefore ASP.NET pages are
>      easy to maintain and write. Also the
>      source code is executed on the server.
>      This provides a lot of power and
>      flexibility to the web pages.
> 7. All the processes are closely monitored and managed by the ASP.NET
>      runtime, so that if process is dead, a
>      new process can be created in its
>      place, which helps keep your
>      application constantly available to
>      handle requests.
> 8. It is purely server-side technology so, ASP.NET code executes on the
>      server before it is sent to the
>      browser.
> 9. Being language-independent, it allows you to choose the language that
>      best applies to your application or
>      partition your application across many
>      languages.
> 10. ASP.NET makes for easy deployment. There is no need to register
>       components because the configuration
>       information is built-in.

Comment: -1 for copying MS promotions.