# What is the best way to cache database query on asp.net-mvc website for performance?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Caching in asp.net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385986/caching-in-asp-net-mvc)

i have an asp.net-mvc site and i am running an expensive database query, where the results rarely change, so i wanted to adding caching,  so when other users bring up the same web page it doesn't go out to the db but just grabs from this cache. (and maybe forced a db get on some expiration timeframe . .)

i have used syscache before to do this 2nd level caching across different users, when i was using nhibernate but (for other reasons not worth discussing) i can't use nhibernate in this case.

I wanted to replicate that same behavior from what i am getting with nhibernate syscache (2nd level cache) in a scenario without nhiberate.

Is this possible and are there recommended solutions for this.  I only have a single web server so i don't need to deal with any distributed issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memcached is a good solution. It basically is a key/value dictionary that runs in memory as a separate process. You can check the cache first, then grab from the database if it has expired.