# The way to cache method's output in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, caching

There is an awesome attribute OutputCache

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 60*60 )]
public ActionResult Index()
```

And it is working fine, but only in case the method is controller's Action Method 
(the reason is in the code which invokes actionMethod).

I want to store the output of some other method of controller (for instance, the code performs some queries to database and returns a collection)

Is there a mechanism like OutputCacheAttribute?
Оr I should write my own caching code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ASP.NET Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) to store data like this. I would recommend against using your own caching model, as you will need to reinvent the wheel on issues like thread safety, stale cache, memory management etc. See also this post : [Caching in asp.net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385986/caching-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I've expected to hear about something which is very close in use (I mean, uses attributes). Seems there are no such ways.
A link where out-of-the-box methods are collected: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997357(v=vs.100).aspx