# Remove single image from OutputCache?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ImageController class that is called to retrieve an image from the database. The result is stored in the cache through use of the attribute [OutputCache].

Here is the controller:

```
[OutputCache(Duration=3600,VaryByParam="name")]
public ActionResult Show(string name)
{
   var imageByte = retrieveByteFromDatabase(name);
   if(imageByte != null && imageByte.Length > 0) 
   {
       return File(imageByte, "image/png");
   }
}
```

Then inside the view, it is being accessed like this:

```
<img class="image" src="@Url.Action( "show", "image", new { name = "Image.png" })" />
```

Now, this is  an image that is uploaded to the database by a user, and will need to be removed from the cache when another image is uploaded. It is uploaded with this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadImage(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
   uploadToDatabase(file);
   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

with the view...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadImage", "Image", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
   <input type="file" name="logo" />
   <button class="button" type="submit">Upload</button>
}
```

Is it possible to remove just this one image from the cache upon uploading a new one? If so - how?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to invalidate cache data \[OutputCache\] from a Controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194140/how-to-invalidate-cache-data-outputcache-from-a-controller)

Comment: using this code flushes everything cached via this function. I just want to be able to single out a specific image and remove it from the flush. This action is used to 'show' several images on the website.

Comment: No it doesn't - `RemoveOutputCacheItem` takes a path to a cached item. So provide it with the URL of your image to remove an image.

Comment: Sorry, I must have not been paying attention - thanks! I got it sorted.