# Custom output cache mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, caching

I am trying to utilise caching on an MVC4 project and I have the following attribute set on my homepage:

```
[OutputCache(Location=OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient,Duration=14400)]
```

This works fine, however the duration is causing me an issue.  What I need is for the cache to expire on the start of a new day (midnight each day).  I could set the duration to be 24 hours however this does not solve my problem with my page having new content on the start of each day.  I have explored the vary by param method and I understand that I can append the date to the URL but this is very messy.  Does anyone know an alternative?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It sounds like you mean [cache invalidation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194140/how-to-invalidate-cache-data-outputcache-from-a-controller)?

Answer (score 1):

A solution will be to extend the `OutputCacheAttribute` and to create a new one that works for midnight because you can set `Duration` in constructor.

```
public class OutputCacheMidnightAttribute : OutputCacheAttribute
{
    public OutputCacheMidnightAttribute()
    {
        // remaining time to midnight
        Duration = (int)((new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0)) - DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay).TotalSeconds;
    }
}
```

And you use it like this

```
[OutputCacheMidnight(Location=OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient)]
```