# .Net Using a view bag variable in a method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, forms, model-view-controller

I am trying to reuse a partial view form between two views (edit and create).

Inside the parent views I declare a variable called form type and I basically just want to use that value in my partial view, but it doesnt seem to work. Here s what I have so far:

Parent View

```
@model Models.Slide
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit Slide";
    ViewBag.FormType = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Slide/_SlideLayout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Edit Slide</h2>

@Html.Partial("_SlideForm", Model)
```

Partial VIew (_SlideForm)

```
@model Models.Slide

 @using (Html.BeginForm(ViewBag.Title, "Slide", null, FormMethod.Post, new  { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
```

I basically just want to declare something outside of the partial view that I can use for the action method within the partial view.

Any help would be greatly apppreciated.

Thanks

Comment: _I basically just want to declare something outside of the partial view that I can use for the action method within the partial view._ Use a [Child Action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530016/what-is-an-mvc-child-action?lq=1) to do this. I made an example for this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33538427/what-is-the-best-practice-of-passing-data-from-a-controller-to-a-view-layout/33551520#33551520).

Comment: i don't get why you don't just declare the @using (Html.BeginForm()) in the parent view and just use the partial view to show the fields

Comment: @JamieD77, agree. That would be the better approach.

Comment: I think a cleaner approach is to use same HttpPost action method for Create and Edit form post. ViewBags are dynamic and i would use those at the very minimum times possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have should work. The problem is that when you pass in parameters like this, the types need to match. Anything out of `ViewBag` is dynamic, so you have to cast to the right type. Also, I would imagine you goofed a bit here, and intended to use `ViewBag.FormType` rather than `ViewBag.Title`. `ViewBag.Title` is not a valid action name, so that's going to fail regardless.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm((string)ViewBag.FormType, ...
```