# Reduce number of query in ASP.NET controller for polling data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to make a request every 10 seconds to a webApi controller in ASP.NET. The controller has to check in the database (SQL Server) if there are new data available (Using enitity framework). Here is the controller side

```
public class RemoteCommandController : ApiController
{
    public Command Get(String id)
    {
        Command command = null;
        ProxyCommand proxycommand = null;
        Device deviceSearch;

        using (var systemDB = new DB())
        {
            deviceSearch = systemDB.Devices.Include("CommandList").Where(d => d.Name.Equals(id)).SingleOrDefault();
            command = deviceSearch.CommandList.LastOrDefault();
        }


        if (command.IsExecuted == false)
        {
            proxycommand = ConvertingObjects.FromCommandToProxy(command);

        }                     

        return proxycommand;
    }
}
```

I want to avoid to query the DB everytime I call this controller. Is there a way to improve this controller in order to reduce the number of querys?
I was thinking of using Session, but I don't think is a good idea...

Comment: What do you mean about caching?

Comment: I would setup [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr)

Answer (score 1):

Just use [output caching](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs).  Add this attribute to your controller:

```
[OutputCache(Duration=10, VaryByParam="none")]
public class RemoteCommandController : ApiController
{
    //etc.....
```

Increase or decrease the duration as needed. If the command list never changes, you can set the duration absurdly high and the controller will only get called once.

Comment: It can help me, but what about if the database data changes? The output cache is able to have a feedback of database changings?

Comment: Yes, you can reset the cache using [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194140/how-to-invalidate-cache-data-outputcache-from-a-controller).